# iTunes 12: How Do I Fix a Problem with a Podcast That iTunes Quit Downloading Episodes For?

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, podcasts, podcasts.app

iTunes quit downloading episodes for one of my subscribed podcasts. The episodes are listed in the iTunes Store but they no longer download. I tried deleting the podcast and resubscribing but it quits at the same spot.

Is there a way for me to reset iTunes or the podcast to get this working? It's working for other subscribers but not for me. The same happens in the Podcasts app for iPhone.

Comment: Can you mention the name of the podcast in question?

Comment: Pass The Mic by The Witness. The last episode that downloaded was on April 9. The latest episode was created on April 22.

Comment: This is the episode that will not download.

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-myth-of-absent-black-fathers/id1435500798?i=1000436034573

Comment: iTunes doesn't actually store the podcast.  It just lists a giant index of podcasts and their locations.  When you play a podcast, Apple goes to the location where the owner of that podcast has it stored.  Most often, if there's a problem getting a specific podcast to play or download, you should contact the podcast owner/creator.

Comment: @fsb I was just able to download and listen to the specific episode all right.

Comment: I can only listen to it from the podcast store. I cannot access it in my iTunes library or the Podcast app. This is why I assume the problem is with my library in iTunes since it never shows up.

Comment: Have you restarted your iPhone and see if that helps?

Comment: I've done several restarts of my iPhone since I started having this problem. It still does not show up. I have rebooted my computer where I sync my iPhone. It does not show up in my library. I'm not sure where to go from here. I have unsubscribed and deleted the podcast and subscribed again. It still stops at the April 9th episode.

Comment: I checked the podcast on my iPhone using Overcast podcast player.  The last episode available for download is April 9th.  It looks like either the creator of that podcast or the company that stores/distributes it is having problems.  The problem is not on your side.

Comment: Okay. I will let them know. Maybe the other people are listening from another service. They post their podcasts on several of them.

Comment: Looks you can play it directly from their site instead.  That's what I just did.  I'm going to add an answer indicating that it's the provider's issue and not yours.  Hopefully, this can help others who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our troubleshooting in the Comments, the problem appears to be from the podcast provider's side.

Using two different podcast players in iOS, the last available episode for download was several weeks ago.  The latest version is not yet available.

By going directly to the podcast owner's site, the episode is playable directly from there.  It will not download to the podcast player, however. The OP will contact the podcast creator for further assistance.

Comment: I just posted a comment about this on Facebook letting them know the problem still exists. They publish the podcast on different platforms. I will use one of them until the iTunes podcast is fixed.

Comment: It looks like they just fixed the problem. I may stick with Spotify since it appears that a good number of the podcasts are on there. The app is a lot easier to use than the Podcasts app is.

Comment: I would also recommend Overcast.  It's a very good free podcast player with a lot of time-saving features.